# Not able to vertically center a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I've been trying to vertically center a div, tried both `position: absolute` and flexbox, neither worked.

Also tried to add styles to both the parent div and child divs, still did not work. It centers horizontally but does not center vertically

here's the HTML for the parent element

```
<div className="all-questions">{renderQuestions}</div>
```

here's the CSS for the parent element

```
.all-questions {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: can you update your question with how the "renderQuestions" looks like

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a **height** then it will work. Try the below code.

```
.all-questions {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to do it with `display: flex;`. [Source: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* center it horizontally (cross axis) */
  align-items: center; /* center it vertically (main axis) */
}

.v-centered {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="v-centered"></div>
</div>
```